# Could Moody's eye always zoom?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Goblet of Fire film, we sometimes see through Moody's magic eye and it's always zooming in on a particular person or group of people.

**Could it always do that, or was it something added after it was stolen?**

We believe it's Moody's original eyepiece because when we see him at the bottom of the enchanted chest, he's covering the left side of this face, presumably because there's a gaping hole there now. So it appears that Crouch Jr. stole the eye from Moody to complete his look.

Comment: Zooming was just a movie gimmick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To answer your question specifically:**

We have no way of knowing if it is something inherent to the eye or is something Barty Crouch Jr added it. It is almost certain that any ability the eye possesses has been there since creation. And we have no reason to suspect that this ability is something Barty Crouch Jr would have added.

**To ramble on a bit:**

There is no evidence in the books to suggest that the eye can zoom. It is almost certainly a cinematic device to allow the audience to know what Moody is focusing on at the moment.

That said, there is so much we don't know about the eye that we can't say for sure that it is unable to (canonically) zoom. After all, it can see through Harry's invisibility cloak (not to mention basically everything else Moody needs to see through), which implies it is an item of great magical virtue.